# Why we have to write robots.txt in website application?

Tags: html, web

I dont know why robots.txt file are using many sites.

Any one can explain me how it is helping to our websites or webpages.

Let me know how to write(syntax and what keywords) robots.txt file.

Thanking you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt

Comment: Did you check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard?

Answer (score 3):

It lists URLs that you don't want bots to hit, so you can keep pages out of search indexes and stop CPU intensive scripts from being repeated hit by automated processes.

The syntax is described at [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) and is basically a series of:

```
User-agent: $PATTERN
```

each followed by any number of

```
Disallow: $PATH_PREFIX
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [DOC](http://www.webconfs.com/what-is-robots-txt-article-12.php) for all information regarding robots.txt. Its basically used for search engine indexing of webpages.